# Determine intervals from kernel density estimation

Tags: cluster-analysis, kernel-density

I have a 1-dimensional data which is (t) where users spend time to complete a task. I applied kernel density estimation from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14034-kernel-density-estimator to remove the outliers who spent unreasonable time. I used the following lines:

```
[bandwidth,density,xmesh]=kde(dur1);
plot(xmesh,density);
```

After applying KDE, I have a problem of defining the local minima to split the data. The following link shows how the curve looks like:
http://s23.postimg.org/6aa1748jf/kde.jpg
I expect to see three clusters, where the middle one contains the reasonable spent time. However, the curve I have got has only one peak.

I am wondering if the steps I am following are correct?

Comment: Try a smaller bandwidth!

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse. Your advice has been taken and it is working.
Could you please tell me how to know the appropriate bandwidth for my data? Also when I locate the minima values at both ends, do you think it is a correct way to split the data there and remove outliers?

Comment: There are only rules of thumb, such as the plug-in estimator. There is no such thing as a "correct way" IMHO if you are working with real data.

Comment: Thanks again – Anony-Mousse. Your answers are very valuable.